# Google cloud VM ports won't open

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to open all ports for incoming trafic in my Google Cloud VM.

I've added a firewall rule to `default` network in GCP.

Firewall rule config:
[image]

Then I've created a VM using the `default` network.

Unfortunately, after I ssh into my VM and scan for open ports, nmap says that only one is open.

```
piotr@worker:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-06 17:17 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Also when I try to telnet from my local machine, I fail on all ports, succed only on port 22.

Should I open ports manually with tool like `ufw` (VM is a Ubuntu 18.0.4).

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Opening ports is one thing but running services (like nginx) on those ports are also necessary for nmap to report them as "open". Are you running any services on those ports? Also, the firewall built-in the VM is a separate entity for the one that GCP provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the action of **opening a firewall port to allow traffic** and **opening a port by listening for connections**. Your VM needs a service (software) listening on a port to act upon something connecting to that port. For example a web server for port 80 or 443.

Comment: After starting a service that listens on port 6443 (nc -l -p 6443) I was able to telnet from my local machine to VM on that port. Thank you John!