# Open port on GCE but still closed

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall, google-vpc

I created a new firewall rule open 8332/8333/18332/18332 tcp ports but when i run nmap i can't see these ports.

It has an service running on 8332 but for me still closed.
External IP: 34.95.163.181

[image]

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: have you checked your OS firewall rule? What other checking do you do? Have you tried accessing your localhost in the browser using the port you've open? You may check again this documentation you might miss some steps. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google cloud VM ports won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249490/google-cloud-vm-ports-wont-open)